# Circular buffer python

Tags: python, deque

I want to do this with a circular buffer(that is x as deque)

```
i = 0
x = []

while True:
    accel_data = sensor.get_accel()
    d = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    t = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
    x.append(accel_data + (d, t))
    i = i + 1
```

I know how to implement a simple circular buffer:

```
from collections import deque
import time

d = deque(maxlen=4)
bool = True
i = 1
y = 0
while bool:
    d.append(i)
    i = i + 1
    print(d)
    time.sleep(1)
```

But I can’t use it to reproduce the first code.

Comment: Why can’t you reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
from collections import deque

container = deque(maxlen=4)
while True:
    accel_data = sensor.get_accel()
    curr_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    curr_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
    entry = accel_data + (curr_date, curr_time)
    container.append(entry)
    print(container)  # this is not strictly necessary
```

A few tips:

1. Use sensible names for the variables you are using.
2. Do not initialize / declare variables you are not going to use.
3. Be more specific in what you are not managing.

Comment: "Do not declare variables you are not going to use." :  i forgot to add few lines before "i=i+1":       for y in range(4):
                                     print x[i][y]

Comment: Be careful in how you introduce that code though, as `x` from your code became `container` whose maximum length is fixed (`4` in the example), so `i` will go out of range if you keep adding it.

Comment: mmm I couldn't try your code because I need my raspberry, but I think there has been a misunderstanding,anyway i will explain better my problem
With first code I've an array ("x"),and in evry step of while I add all those information.So after 4 steps,for example it will be:               
                 0.48 , 0.89 , 1.2 16/12/17 20.45.34 ==> x[0] -----------0.48 , 0.90 , 1.4 16/12/17 20.45.35 ==> x[1]
        ---------- 0.48 , 0.91 , 1.2 16/12/17 20.45.36  ==>x[2]
        ------0.48 , 0.94 , 1.2 16/12/17 20.45.37==>  x[3]

Comment: So the "maxlen" is not referred to "j"( the elements in x[i],that are always 5),but to "i"

Comment: This code works also if you change `container = deque(maxlen=4)` with `container = []` as you (ideally) originally had. The `list` version will let `container` grow by 1 at each iteration, hence if you can access `container` with an ever growing index like `container[i]` (assuming you have `i += 1` or similar somewhere inside the loop and you had initialized `i = 0` outside the loop). On the other hand, if `container` is now a `deque`, accessing it when `i`  is larger than its max size, will cause the `container[i]` to get out of range for some value of `i`, regardless of what is in `entry`.

Comment: How can I "impose" the circular buffer on the number of arrays and not on the number of element of the array??

Comment: Possibly, just `print(entry)` or replace `x[i]` with `entry`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'impose'? which arrays? there are no arrays as far as I can see

Comment: From my understanding, in your code you had a list of tuples `list[tuple]`, and the above code replaces it with `deque[tuple]`. Now the loop `for y in range(4): print x[i][y]` seems to me that is meant to print the elements of the `tuple`. This is now in `entry`, so either `print(entry)` or `for item in entry: print(item)` (with appropriate indentations) or - worse, as you explicitly need to know `entry` size - `for y in range(4): print(entry[y])` should work.